# What Glmm method is best to analize Mortality Rate as a response variable

Tags: r, glmm, gamma-distribution, mortality

I am investigating the effect of two explanatory variables (one continuous and one binary) on my continuous response variable (Mortality rate). This variable is a proportion and resembles a gamma distribution. I first thought a zero inflated gamma glmm would do the trick but R returns an error message stating that a glmm within the gamma family will not accept non-positives values.
Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Tamsin Harper! Even if we migrate this to [stats.se] (which is a _much_ more appropriate place to discuss "best model"), there is too little information here to say much with confidence. Please [edit] the question to make this *reproducible*. This includes sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `data.frame(x=...,y=...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))` into a [code block]). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Beta regression can handle outcomes that are proportions. The may be other modeling frameworks depending on how close the “rates” are to 0 or 1. I put “rates” in quotes because my use of the term requires that time units be in the denominator. Events per unit time or events per risk set per unit time.

Comment: This topic is frequently referred to as survival analysis and it has its own methods, for ex Cox Hazard Model to name one.

Comment: In particular, please say more about how you are measuring mortality rate, why you are using a mixed model, and the nature of the grouping variable(s) for the mixed model. Please provide the extra information requested in this and other comments by editing the question itself, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.